# How can i print a report from odoo server actions (GUI)

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

How can I make a server action in the **GUI** of odoo 10 to print the custom picking report
Report id: id=690

(I am trying to make an automated action to print al new confirmed orders)

Comment: how is the server hosted

Comment: on a rented server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just noticed that this module supports odoo 10

https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/15.0/printnode_base/

This is probably your best bet.

To get the report from the odoo server:
`{server}/report/pdf/{report_id}/{object_id}`
example:

```
https://odoo.yourcompany.com/report/pdf/account.report_invoice_with_payments/70
```

I don't have access to Odoo 10, but for modern Odoos you can generate the report like that:

```py
pdf_data = self.env.ref('account.report_invoice_with_payments').with_user(SUPERUSER_ID)._render_qweb_pdf([invoice.id])[0]
```

This `pdf_data` is pdf data as bytes that can be posted to the server or saved to a file.